# Counting word frequencies in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am leaning Haskell and decided to do the following [lab assignment](http://www.scs.stanford.edu/11au-cs240h/labs/lab1.html) from *CS240h: Functional Systems in Haskell*. I welcome any advice on more idiomatic coding style and performance tips.

Notes:

- I chose `Data.HashTable` on the assumption that it would be faster than `Data.Map` as the number of entries increase. **Edit:** this seems to be an erroneous assumption as timing on about 5M of input has `Data.Map` at 3.5s and `Data.HashTable` at 5.3s.
- Some of the `_ <- mapM` does not feel right.
- I also wondered if using some sort of `ByteString` would be better, but I was also confused on how to make it work with UTF-8 and coming up with a suitable hash function, so I dropped that idea.

Here is the code I ended with:

```
module Lab1 where      

import Prelude hiding (lookup, readFile, getContents)
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import System.IO.UTF8 (readFile, getContents)
import Data.Char (isAlpha, toLower, isPunctuation)
import Data.HashTable
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List (sortBy, dropWhileEnd)

type Frequencies = HashTable String Int

-- Get relevant words according to the instructions in the assignment.
-- Convert to lowercase, keep the single quotes ("Don't" -> "don't")
getWords :: String -> [String]
getWords str = let
  isGoodChar c = isAlpha(c) || c `elem` "`'"
  chunk s = let (word, notGood) = span isGoodChar s
                (_, rest) = span (not . isGoodChar) notGood 
            in word : (if rest == "" then [] else chunk rest)
  trim = (dropWhile isPunctuation) . (dropWhileEnd isPunctuation)
  lower = map toLower str
  in [trimmed | word <- chunk lower, let trimmed = trim word, trimmed /= ""]

emptyFrequencies :: IO Frequencies
emptyFrequencies = fromList hashString []

increaseCount :: Frequencies -> String -> IO Frequencies
increaseCount frequencies word = do
  maybeCount <- lookup frequencies word
  let count = fromMaybe 0 maybeCount
  _ <- update frequencies word (count + 1)
  return frequencies

countWords :: Frequencies -> String -> IO Frequencies
countWords frequencies str = do
  _ <- mapM (increaseCount frequencies) (getWords str) 
  return frequencies

-- read list files from arguments or use stdin
processInputs :: IO Frequencies
processInputs = do
  frequencies <- emptyFrequencies
  args <- getArgs
  contents <- if args == [] then sequence [getContents]
              else mapM readFile args
  _ <- mapM (countWords frequencies) contents
  return frequencies

printFrequencies :: IO ()
printFrequencies = do
  frequencies <- processInputs
  list <- toList frequencies
  let sorted = sortBy (compare `on` negate . snd) list
      maxLengthWord = maximum $ map (length . fst) sorted
      maxLengthBar = 80 - maxLengthWord - 1
      maxCount = (snd . head) sorted
      baseUnit = (fromIntegral maxLengthBar) / (fromIntegral maxCount) :: Double
      makeBar count = replicate (round $ (fromIntegral count) * baseUnit) '#'
      pad w = take (maxLengthWord + 1) $ (w ++ cycle " ")
      bars = [(pad w) ++ bar | (w, count) <- sorted, let bar = makeBar count, bar /= ""]
  _ <- mapM putStrLn bars     
  return ()
```

---

I spent a bit more time and find out I could use `foldlM` and `mapM_` in a couple places.

Also I ran the code through *hlint* and it pointed out that `break isGoodChar` could replace `span (not . isGoodChar)` and that I had some unnecessary parentheses. So here is the updated version:

```
module Lab1 where      

import Prelude hiding (lookup, readFile, getContents)
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import System.IO.UTF8 (readFile, getContents)
import Data.Char (isAlpha, toLower, isPunctuation)
import Data.HashTable
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List (sortBy, dropWhileEnd)
import Data.Foldable (foldlM)

type Frequencies = HashTable String Int

-- Get relevant words according to the instructions in the assignment.
-- Convert to lowercase, keep the single quotes ("Don't" -> "don't")
getWords :: String -> [String]
getWords str = let
  isGoodChar c = isAlpha c || c `elem` "`'"
  chunk s = let (word, notGood) = span isGoodChar s
                (_, rest) = break isGoodChar notGood 
            in word : (if null rest then [] else chunk rest)
  trim = dropWhile isPunctuation . dropWhileEnd isPunctuation
  lower = map toLower str
  in [trimmed | word <- chunk lower, let trimmed = trim word, trimmed /= ""]

emptyFrequencies :: IO Frequencies
emptyFrequencies = fromList hashString []

increaseCount :: Frequencies -> String -> IO Frequencies
increaseCount frequencies word = do
  maybeCount <- lookup frequencies word
  let count = fromMaybe 0 maybeCount
  _ <- update frequencies word (count + 1)
  return frequencies

countWords :: Frequencies -> String -> IO Frequencies
countWords frequencies str =
  foldlM increaseCount frequencies (getWords str)

-- read list files from arguments or use stdin
processInputs :: IO Frequencies
processInputs = do
  frequencies <- emptyFrequencies
  args <- getArgs
  contents <- if null args
                then sequence [getContents]
                else mapM readFile args
  foldlM countWords frequencies contents

printFrequencies :: IO ()
printFrequencies = do
  frequencies <- processInputs
  list <- toList frequencies
  let sorted = sortBy (compare `on` negate . snd) list
      maxLengthWord = maximum $ map (length . fst) sorted
      maxLengthBar = 80 - maxLengthWord - 1
      maxCount = (snd . head) sorted
      baseUnit = fromIntegral maxLengthBar / fromIntegral maxCount :: Double
      makeBar count = replicate (round $ fromIntegral count * baseUnit) '#'
      pad w = take (maxLengthWord + 1) (w ++ cycle " ")
      bars = [pad w ++ bar | (w, count) <- sorted, let bar = makeBar count, bar /= ""]
  mapM_ putStrLn bars
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside do notation, you don't need to use `_ <-` to discard the value of a computation. So
`_ <- update frequencies word (count + 1)` can be written as `update frequencies word (count + 1)`

Haskell programmers tend to prefer immutable collections like `Data.Map` or `Data.IntMap` over hash tables. `Data.HashTable` uses mutable references and requires you to work inside the IO monad. Generally, it is good practice to relegate the IO monad to the outer layers of your program and keep the core pure.

To work efficiently with Unicode data, consider using the [text](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text) package.

Comment: I added the `_ <- ` because eclipsefp reports a warning if I don't. So I thought that was a best practice. Yes, `Data.Map` turned out to be more efficient and also let me parallelize the code. I will try out the text package to see if it speeds up the code.

Comment: Using the `text` package worked great! It brought down the time from 3.5s to 2.1s.

Comment: Handling strings as list of characters (like the String type does) is conceptually elegant but can be inefficient for intensive string processing. In those cases it's better to use `text`.

Comment: Yes, you will get a warning if you use `mapM` and discard its results without being explicit (i.e. writing `_ <- mapM ...`).

However, instead of using `mapM`, you can use `mapM_` which is the same as `mapM` except that it ignores the results from the actions. This is a common pattern, and there is also `forM_`, `sequence_` and so on.